# Changing float rounding mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Having the code like below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma fenv_access (on)

void precission(void) {
    unsigned int control_word;
    int err;
    float a = 10.0, b = 3.0;
    char MsgBuff[300];
    
    err = _controlfp_s(&control_word, _RC_UP, _MCW_RC);
    if (err) {
        sprintf_s(MsgBuff, 300, "Error \n");
        OutputDebugStringA(MsgBuff);
    }

    sprintf_s(MsgBuff, 300, "float division : %.3f / %.3f = %.3f \n", a, b, a / b);
    OutputDebugStringA(MsgBuff);

    err = _controlfp_s(&control_word, _RC_DOWN, _MCW_RC);
    if (err) {
        sprintf_s(MsgBuff, 300, "Error \n");
        OutputDebugStringA(MsgBuff);
    }

    sprintf_s(MsgBuff, 300, "float division : %.3f / %.3f = %.3f \n", a, b, a / b);
    OutputDebugStringA(MsgBuff);
}
```

I'd expect to receive sth. like that:

```
float division : 10.000 / 3.000 = 3.334 
float division : 10.000 / 3.000 = 3.333
```

but got:

```
float division : 10.000 / 3.000 = 3.333 
float division : 10.000 / 3.000 = 3.333
```

Why doesn't changing the rounding mode works?

PS.

I'm running the code on VS2020 on Win 10 64-bit

Comment: Pleasse explain your expectations in detail. Why are you expecting precisely those values?

Comment: Have you tried [the standard `fesetround` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/fenv/feround) instead? As in `fesetround(FE_UPWARD)`?

Comment: formatted output not affected by fp settings, afaik, and it removes more significant digits than you actually have.

Comment: @Yunnosch It's nothing to explain. I just expected changing the roudup mode to `_RC_UP` results in 3.334 and for `_RC_DOWN` results in 3.333 - simple? Yeah - but seems doesn't work!

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie "formatted output not affected by fp settings" so how to investigate the change?

Comment: Try debug step by step, have variable to store result and  inspect them. Or adjust formatting so it would show entire content of float

Comment: `%.3f` -> `%.17f` for instance.

Comment: I get it rounded down in both cases. [The diff is small](https://rextester.com/GSBJH24887)

Comment: @TedLyngmo `10.000 / 3.000 = 3.33333349` is not down, but up :-)

Comment: @rustyx  Yeah, I increased the precision to show that the diff between the rounded up and rounded down value is so small that with only default precision, it'll still look rounded down. I should have phrased it differently :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you could Multiply the number, round it, and divide it.

```
int main()
{

    float a = 10.000;
    float b = 3.000;
    float c=a/b;
    float d = (int)(c * 1000+1) / 1000.0;
    cout << d;//d=3.334

    return 0;
}
```